# my landlord won't let me in on the day my tenancy begins, is this legal?

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property, property, tenant, lease

My tenancy begins on July 1st, however as this is a Sunday my letting agent will not give me the keys on this day. I really need to move my stuff in on July 1st, can I claim that not allowing me to have the keys and move in on this day is in breach of contract?

I live in the UK and will be renting this house with two other tenants

Answer (score 11):

If you are prevented from entering the property on the day the contract says the tenancy begins that is a breach of the contract.

If you suffer a loss as a result of the breach, you are entitled to be restored to the position you'd be in had the loss not occurred. For example, if you had additional removal fees and a hotel bill resulting from this breach, you'd be entitled to claim those costs. Generally the landlord would be liable for this.

It is no defence that the agent is unavailable to give you the keys - they should have accounted for the day being a Sunday or started the term on a day when someone would be available.

I suggest getting in touch with the landlord in the first instance, civilly explain the situation and ask if they can arrange for you to enter the property on the given date - they might not know what is going on. Keep a log/diary of your communications with the agent and the landlord. Make sure you have a plan B for somewhere to stay. Call Shelter too, for free advice.